# javascript object does not provide the value with its property name

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on a project in react.js.

I have a json array which contains the list of players with their details. I am using the json array in app.js component. But not the whole array. I want to use only a single object from the array. This is the json file I am using:

```
`{
    "user":[
        {"name":"Mahendra Singh","city":"Ranchi","age":"35","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/11189261_759116200870985_1595157767_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Virat Kohli","city":"Delhi","age":"28","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10004088_1491055334449687_1187165020_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Suresh Raina","city":"Punjab","age":"26","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10817863_856543214397968_517239188_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Chahel","city":"Noida","age":"25","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10919749_326992714172441_299394464_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Krishna Kumar","city":"Noida","age":"24","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10617007_939025979457209_6938406_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Gautam Gambhir","city":"Mumbai","age":"26","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1168617_1435408473368301_409182770_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Sachin Tendulkar","city":"Mumbai","age":"48","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/11189836_754178218029431_2102772742_n.jpg"},
        {"name":"Sauravh Ganguly","city":"Bengal","age":"50","url":"http://maggiesadler.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10843869_1658219887738208_2033326788_n.jpg"}
    ]

}`
```

This is the app.js where I want to use that data

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
var userjson = require('./user.json');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { user:[],

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ user : userjson.user})

}

  render() {
    console.log(name);
    var user = this.state.user; //user is a list of user from the state
    var currentUser = user[0]; 
    console.log(currentUser);
    console.log(currentUser['name']); //error
    console.log(currentUser['age']); //error
    console.log(currentUser['city']);// error

    var player = {'name':'Sachin','Age':'48','City':'Mumbai'};
    console.log(player);
    console.log(player['name']); //while this will work
    console.log(player['City']);
    console.log(player['Age']);

    for(var index = 0 ;index < user.length ;index++){
      if(index > 0){ break; }
      var name = user[index].name;
      var city = user[index].city;
      var age  = user[index].age;
      var url  = user[index].url;
    }

  return (
      <div className="main-container">
                <div className="user">
                    <div className="user-pic">
                    <img src = {url} alt="image not found"/>
                    </div>
                <div className="user-box">
                    <div className="user-name">
                    {name}
                    </div>
                    <div className="user-city">
                    {age}
                    </div>
                    <div className="user-age">
                    {city}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Var player is similar to the currentUser, and gives value with their property name but currentUser does not provide the value with their property name?

Comment: Can you give us the result of `console.log(currentUser);`? The line before the error happen.

Comment: Seems like you are forgetting to parse the json-string to get an object. var userjson = JSON.parse(require('./user.json')); might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComponentDidMount run after first render of Component. You need move set data in constructor fuction or check it conditionally in render. You can also use `componentWillMount`

```
var userjson = require('./user.json');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { user: userjson.user,

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){

}
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer but it not works , but it gives me an direction, if we set state before the first rendering , then it will work.
 ex:componentWillMount(){
 this.setState({user : userjson.user})
}